# WinAPI: why does CreateSymbolicLink return true despite insufficient privileges? Error 1314

Tags: winapi, error-handling, symlink, dllimport, privileges

I am calling [CreateSymbolicLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinkw) using `DllImport` for `Kernel32.dll` in .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 11. The function is supposed to return `true` on success and `false` on failure, but if it is run **without the right privileges** to create a symbolic link, it still returns `true`.

After returning `true`, checking `GetLastError` (or, in .NET, `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`) returns the error code 1314 (`ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`) which I expected because I'm not running it with admin privileges.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

public static class SymlinkProblemExample {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string symlinkFileName, string targetFileName, int flags);

    public static void Main() {
        string symlink = "symlink-to-foo";
        string target = "foo.txt";
        int flags = 0x0; // 0x0 means the target is a file, not a directory.

        bool result = CreateSymbolicLink(symlink, target, flags);
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        
        Console.WriteLine(result); // True
        Console.WriteLine(err); // 1314
    }
}
```

**Why does `CreateSymbolicLink` return `true` despite failing due to a lack of privileges?** Is this quirk specific to `CreateSymbolicLink`, or do other WinAPI functions also return `true` after failing due to a lack of privileges (error 1314)? I expect it to return `false` if it fails, and lacking privileges seems like a failure mode.

Only admins can create symbolic links, unless Developer Mode is enabled in Windows. I intentionally did not pass the flag `0x2` to `CreateSymbolicLink`, because that would use Developer Mode to circumvent the privilege requirement.

I can work around this issue by checking the WinAPI error code, but I want to know why this decision was made in WinAPI (or maybe it's a bug).

---

### Solution

Thanks to Remy in the comments: `CreateSymbolicLink` is not buggy or quirky, it actually returns `false` for privilege errors as expected. The bug is in my `DllImport` call: in the WinAPI, [`BOOL` is a 4-byte `int` while `BOOLEAN` is just a byte](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923). `CreateSymbolicLink` returns a `BOOLEAN` (1 byte), but when I specified the DllImported function to return a C# `bool`, it expects to consume a `BOOL` (4 bytes) from the WinAPI.

As a result, the marshaller reads 3 extra bytes of garbage data after the 1 byte of `CreateSymbolicLink`'s return value. If that garbage data has any bits set to 1, then the whole 32-bit `BOOL` is read as `True`.

This is the fix to the imported function signature:

```cs
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
private static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string symlinkFileName, string targetFileName, int flags);
```

The attribute `[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` means "expect this function to return 1 byte". [I1 is a signed byte type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=netframework-4.8) often used to convert 1-byte `BOOLEAN` values.

Comment: With most win32 APIs calling GetLastError is not meaningful on success. Does the link actually exist before running this program? If so it would not surprise me if CreateSymbolLink were to succeed even without the privilege being held.

Comment: The bug is in your code, not in `CreateSymbolicLink()` itself. `CreateSymbolicLink()` returns a `BOOLEAN` (aka 1-byte `unsigned char`), but by default [PInvoke expects a C# `bool` to map to a Win32 `BOOL` (aka 4-byte `int`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-data-with-platform-invoke) instead. So on function exit, the PInvoke marshaller is reading too many bytes and misinterpreting the value.  You need to use `[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` to map the `bool` properly to get the correct value.

Comment: [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) makes those kinds of bugs simply disappear.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir It returns `true` regardless of the symlink existing, but that's an unrelated bug, as Remy says. `GetLastError` is meaningful: by using `SetLastError = true`, I guarantee that the [error code is set to zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) before that PInvoked function is called. If `GetLastError` is zero, the call succeeded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are correct, this is a bug in my code. Now I know the difference between `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`.

Comment: Don't include the problem resolution in the question. Post an answer instead and mark it as a solution (although kind of hard on a duplicate).